# multi-level repeating of <tr><td> using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

I am really having a hard time implementing this using AngularJS.
Below is the expected output.

```
                          child1-1
           child1[+][-]
                          child1-2
```

parent[+][-]

```
           child2[+][-]
```

Whenever parent's [+] is clicked, child1 and child2 are displayed.
If the child1's [+] is clicked its children child1-1 and child1-2 will be displayed.

I really don't know what to do on the 3rd level.

Answer (score 0):

Each child-having object could have its own boolean depicting whether its children are visible or not. Then on `ng-click` you could toggle that boolean, and reveal its children with `ng-class`.

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/omobW1f8r6382i7esZ5J?p=preview)

Edit: [**Bonus, recursive Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/yxO4FsXh7M4N0cFIyzki?p=preview) based on [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0U9lY9yR0AQXx8q1nfrY?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="parent in nested">
    <td>
      <strong
        ng-click="toggleChildren( parent )"
        ng-class="{ hasChildren: parent.children.length, plus:parent.toggled }">
        {{ parent.title }}
      </strong>
      <ul ng-class="{ noShow: !parent.toggled }">
        <li ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
          <strong
            ng-click="toggleChildren( child )"
            ng-class="{ hasChildren: child.children.length, plus: child.toggled }">
            {{ child.title }}
          </strong>
          <ul ng-class="{ noShow: !child.toggled }">
            <li ng-repeat="grandchild in child.children">
              <strong>{{ grandchild.title }}</strong>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>            
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
  .noShow{display:none}
  .hasChildren:after{content:'+'}
  .hasChildren.plus:after{content:'-'}
```

**JS**

```
    $scope.toggleChildren = function( scope )
    {
      scope.toggled = !scope.toggled;
    }
```

PS regarding tags: "java" is to "javascript" as "car" is to "carpet"; I don't think your question has to do with the former.